# 2 decimal time display on audio player

Tags: javascript, audio-player

For my audio player, how can I display both times in just 2 decimals?

Right now the counter shows ... 0:7, 0:8, 0:9, 0:10, 0:11

But it should be like:

0:07, 0:08, 0:09, 0:10, 0:11

and the total time of the audio file is displayed like: 273.298866

But it should be:

4:13

---

```
var duration = document.getElementById('fullDuration');
var currentTime = document.getElementById('currentTime');

duration.innerHTML = mytrack.duration;


mytrack.addEventListener("loadedmetadata",function(){
    var minutes = parseInt(mytrack.duration / 60);
    var seconds = parseInt(mytrack.duration % 60);
    duration.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds;
})
```

And

```
function update(){
  if(!mytrack.ended){
    var playedMinutes = parseInt(mytrack.currentTime/60);
    var playedSeconds = parseInt(mytrack.currentTime%60);
    currentTime.innerHTML = playedMinutes + ':' + playedSeconds;

    var size = parseInt(mytrack.currentTime*barSize/mytrack.duration);
    progressBar.style.width = size + "px";

  }
  else{
    currentTime.innerHTML = "0.00";
    playButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url(file:///Users/Pier/Desktop/Play%20button.png)';
    progressBar.style.width = "0px";
    window.clearInterval(updateTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: `var m = minutes.toString(); if(m.length === 1)minutes = '0'+m;`

Comment: I would just add a simple if statement prior to setting the innerHTML, so something like: ```currentTime.innerHTML = playedMinutes + ':' + ((playedSeconds < 10) ? ('0' + playedSeconds): playedSeconds)```

Comment: Thanks for thinking along! Didn't manage to make either of those work - it just shows 0:00 and I can't press play anymore. Or am I adding them in the wrong locations? Where exactly would they go? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The modern way to do this is with [`String.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), but it [doesn't work with IE](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=pad-start-end):

```
currentTime.textContent = playedMinutes + ':' + playedSeconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');
```

Comment: Looks like it gave me a NaN :/

Comment: Then you need to make sure `playedSeconds` and, by extension, `mytrack.currentTime` are numbers. (And provided they are, use `Math.floor` instead of `parseInt` to get the integer remainder.)